# Adding an active class to menu using jquery problem

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to Jquery/JS and still learning. I need to add an "active" class to my menu. I know there are already many similar questions across this forum and web as well but nothing works. It had bugged me for days and I still couldn't figure out the problem.

Here is my HTML :

```
<nav id="nav-menu-container">
  <ul class="nav-menu">
    <li class="menu-active"><a href="/site/index">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/site/about">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="/site/news">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="/site/contact">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="/site/login">Login</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav><!-- #nav-menu-container -->
```

Here is my code to add the class:

```
    $('.nav-menu a, #mobile-nav a').on('click', function() {
 if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
    if ($(this).parents('.nav-menu').length) {
           $('.nav-menu .menu-active').removeClass('menu-active');
           $(this).closest('li').addClass('menu-active');
        }

     if ($('body').hasClass('mobile-nav-active')) {
              $('body').removeClass('mobile-nav-active');
              $('#mobile-nav-toggle i').toggleClass('fa-times fa-bars');
              $('#mobile-body-overly').fadeOut();
            }
            return false;
          }

    });
```

I'm sorry I didn't explain it in detail before. I want the link menu to be redirecting to another page. The code originally came from a one page-web theme I use, but I customize it to fit my multi-page web application.

Thanks again.

Comment: how do you want to add the class on click?

Comment: What `$(this)` refers to?

Comment: When you will click on the anchor page will be redirected to another page

Comment: What is `$(this)` on your code (i.e to what it is referencing), please complete the code so we can see all the context.

Comment: if you are directed to another page you should use local storage(or other storage) to store menu state

Comment: On the clicking time you can keep the value in the localstorage and on pageload time you can check the state from the localstorate and make that active

Comment: Please produce enough code for us to replicate the problem as a [MCVE]. " but nothing works" is not very helpful, what happens that shouldn't? What doesn't happen but should? Are there any console errors?

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```js
$('.nav-menu').on('click', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.nav-menu .menu-active').removeClass('menu-active');
  $(e.target).parent('li').addClass('menu-active');
});
```

```css
li.menu-active a {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="nav-menu-container">
  <ul class="nav-menu">
    <li class="menu-active"><a href="/site/index">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/site/about">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="/site/news">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="/site/contact">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="/site/login">Login</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: @guradio OP not mention any redirect

Comment: see anchor tags' href

Comment: He is wanting to toggle class `'menu-active'` with jQuery.. No idea if this is a SPA o not..

Comment: @guradio we have no idea if `if ($(this).parents('.nav-menu').length) {` is in a click event handler or not. The OP really needs to clarify what they are trying to do.

Comment: @JonP is premature to answer such OP then?but seeing the href it should redirect the the page on click on default behaviour right? Does that need explanation?

Comment: @guradio his code only shows an `if` statement.. And is needing to handle a class toggle with jQuery

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple pages try with this. the below code activate the menu with the current page
when you have like this.

```
    <nav id="nav-menu-container">
      <ul class="nav-menu">
        <li><a href="/index">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="/news">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="/login">Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav><!-- #nav-menu-container -->

<script>
        $(function() {
          $('nav a[href^="/' + location.pathname.split("/")[1] + '"]').addClass('menu-active');
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="side-bar">
<ul>
    <li><a href="xtz.com">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Who we are</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">What to expect</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Representative clients</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Success stories</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Current litigation</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">What if you could not be a doctor?</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

**script**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    alert(localStorage.getItem("selectedolditem"));
                $("#side-bar a").click(function () {
                    var id = $(this);

                    $(".active").removeClass("active");
                    $(id).addClass("active");
                    localStorage.setItem("selectedolditem", $(id).text());
                   alert(localStorage.getItem("selectedolditem"));
                });

                var selectedolditem = localStorage.getItem('selectedolditem');

                if (selectedolditem !== null) {

                    $("a:contains('" + selectedolditem + "')").addClass("active");
                }
            });
```

**css**

```
.active {color:red;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how it can work with localStorage. 
I am afraid the snippet tool does NOT allow localStorage so you will have to see it working here:
https://repl.it/@PaulThomas1/BraveOffbeatByte

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  // try and load
  if (localStorage) {
    let active = localStorage.getItem('activeMenu');
    if (active) document.querySelector(`a[class="${active}"]`).classList.add('active');
  }
});

document.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  // try and save
  if (e.target.matches('a') && localStorage) {
    localStorage.setItem('activeMenu', e.target.className);
  }
});
```

```html
<nav id="nav-menu-container">
  <ul class="nav-menu">
    <li class="menu-active"><a href="/site/index" class="home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/site/about" class="about">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="/site/news" class="news">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="/site/contact" class="contact">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="/site/login" class="login">Login</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<!-- #nav-menu-container -->
```